# How to get elements of specific class inside a div already found in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I need is to find a div with particular id, then find any element with particular class inside it and make the first of them invisible. I have tried

```
var hostDivName = "theHostDivName";
var hostDiv = document.getElementsByName(hostDivName);
var theElements = hostDiv.getElementsByClassName("theClassDivName");
theElements[0].style.display = "none";
```

But it fails on `hostDiv.getElementsByClassName("theClassDivName");` with

```
Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByClassName'
```

error.

So what is the right way? I'd prefer using pure JavaScript (rather than jQuery or whatever) as far as this seems reasonable.

Comment: getElementsBy* functions return an array of elements, you need to loop through it.

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickEvans, indeed, seems obvious when you get it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's an ID, why are you using `getElementsByName` and not `getElementById`

```
var hostDivName = "theHostDivName";

var hostDiv = document.getElementById(hostDivName);

var theElements = hostDiv.getElementsByClassName("theClassDivName");

theElements[0].style.display = "none";
```

Assuming you meant name, and not ID

```
var hostDiv = document.getElementsByName(hostDivName)[0];
```