# How to loop through div tags with same class name

Tags: javascript

On my page, I have 5 div tags named "dropdown". I want to find all "a" tags under each "dropdown" div tag. I hope I am explaining this properly but this is what I have. Can someone confirm that it is right:

```
var dropdownDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
for(i = 0; i < dropdownDivs.length;i++)

var lnks = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: Why not use JQuery?

Comment: because jquery is bad for performances ... and you don't need jquery when doing some basic html stuffs... Stop selling jqeury on every website.

Comment: @DerekBrown Because world doesn't revolve around JQuery. Small & Simple JavaScript should be done without JQuery.

Comment: @sheplu who is to say the primary goal is performance? If OP would use a lot of the functionality, JQuery may be worthwhile.

Comment: not at all ! why do you want to use jquery in this case when it's 1 line with pure javascript ? do you think ONE line is too much ?
Jquery should be used when, and only when, you need to use a lot of widget like colorpicker, datepicker and other stuff. and that's all. 
Trying to use jquery on every site, where you need to do one line of javascript is, for me, something bad.

Comment: @sheplu because 1) it's more cross-compatible and 2) it's easier to read and edit. The fact that this question had to be asked speaks volumes.

Comment: 1) No it's not. every actual browsers work fine with querySelector(). And jquery 3 dropped support for old browsers. So nothing here.
2) Easier ? `document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a');` VS `$('.dropdown a')` ? indeed two words in pure js versus loading a full lib ...
3) No jquery tag in the question, so i think he want pure js
4) Perf http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: @DerekBrown Most JS things work just fine without jQuery. There are only a couple gotchas, and those only apply to much older browsers now. Readability and editablity are personal opinion. Having done both extensively, I vastly prefer vanilla JS for both. This question is completely unrelated to jQuery, and using it wouldn't magically solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the links inside the for loop:

```js
var dropdownDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

var lnks = [];

for (i = 0; i < dropdownDivs.length; i++) {
  lnks.push(...dropdownDivs[i].getElementsByTagName('a'));
}
lnks.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>
```

You can shorten it to a single call, by using [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var lnks = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a');

lnks.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.color = "red";
})
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a')`. [Here's the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAllhttp://) on `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: you need to add `' '` inside querySelector

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdownDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

var links = dropdownDivs.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

You do not need the for loop.

[How to get elements of specific class inside a div already found in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296611/how-to-get-elements-of-specific-class-inside-a-div-already-found-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

One line with pure javascript

```
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a');
console.log(test);
```

My HTML for test

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a> TOTO </a>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        <a> TOTOB </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a> TOTOC </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a> TOTOD </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your for loop itself is probably correct. Your problem though may be what you are doing with it in the loop.

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('target');

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  console.log(divs[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="target"><a href="A">A</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="B">B</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="C">C</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="D">D</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="E">E</a></div>
```

In your example, you're just setting them into a variable each time. If there is more to it, then that might be okay. If you're trying to collect them all into one variable, you'll want to put them in an array instead.

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
let anchors = [];

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  anchors.push(divs[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]);
}

console.log(anchors);
```

```html
<div class="target"><a href="A">A</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="B">B</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="C">C</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="D">D</a></div>
<div class="target"><a href="E">E</a></div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help.  I want to start with the first dropdown div, print all the "a" tags, then go to the next dropdown div, and print all the "a" tags ect.... I have 5 tab and under those tabs are links. My code is supposed to log where a user clicks. So if you click on a link under the first tab, it will log "column 1| link 1".

Comment: If you want to loop through all of them, you would just have a second loop in your first loop to go through and read each anchor. However, if you want it to do something on click, that's an entirely different question with entirely different code. I'd recommend actually creating a new question and expand on what you're actually looking for.

Comment: How would i write a loop inside another  loop? Is that what you did in your example above?

Comment: A loop inside a loop would be to have `for(...) { for (...) {} }`. Just two for loops inside one another. Also known as a nested for loop. As I said though, if it involves clicking, the solution is actually radically different and you won't need for loops at all. I'd start another question.

Comment: Ok i will start another question

Answer (score 0):

As other people already suggested how to do it through java script, If want to go with jquery this can help.

```
$(".dropdown").each(function(){
    $(this).find("a").each(function(){
    console.log(this);
  })
})
```